# Reconhecimento facial em Tempo real no Android

Tags: android-studio, opencv, android-camera

Bom dia!

Estou criando um aplicativo de reconhecimento facial em tempo real. O aplicativo deve comparar a imagem em vídeo com uma imagem gravada.

Em praticamente todas as pesquisas que fiz o mais indicado a ser utilizado foi o [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html).

Implementei com este [tutorial](http://blog.codeonion.com/2015/11/25/creating-a-new-opencv-project-in-android-studio/), a biblioteca contendo a versão 3.1.0 do OpenCV.

Estou lendo todas as informações da API. Porém, não estou encontrando um método para reconhecimento facial, onde eu possa usar o onDraw e desenhar um quadrado no rosto e muito menos como utilizar o reconhecimento facial e comparar com outro rosto.

Alguém já utilizou esta API? Recomenda o uso desta ou de outra ferramenta?

Abaixo o fonte:

**ShowCameraActivity**

```
public class ShowCameraActivity  extends AppCompatActivity implements CvCameraViewListener2 {

private static final String TAG = "OCVSample::Activity";
private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;
private boolean              mIsJavaCamera = true;
private MenuItem             mItemSwitchCamera = null;
Mat mRgba;
Mat mRgbaF;
Mat mRgbaT;

public ShowCameraActivity() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Instantiated new " + this.getClass());
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.show_camera);
    mOpenCvCameraView = (JavaCameraView) findViewById(R.id.show_camera_activity_java_surface_view);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {

    mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
    mRgbaF = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
    mRgbaT = new Mat(width, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    mRgba.release();
}

@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    Core.transpose(mRgba, mRgbaT);
    Imgproc.resize(mRgbaT, mRgbaF, mRgbaF.size(), 0,0, 0);
    return mRgba;
}

private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
        mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization");
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_1_0, this, mLoaderCallback);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");
        mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

**show_camera.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:opencv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/show_camera_activity_java_surface_view"
    opencv:show_fps="false"
    opencv:camera_id="back" />
```

Inserido no **Manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
```

PS: A dúvida [Reconhecimento Facial](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29783/reconhecimento-facial-no-android) de 2014 indicava como resposta o uso do [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html) onde o link está down. Também lí sobre o [FaceDetection](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/10/28/implementing-face-detection-in-android) muito bom, por sinal. Mas a maioria dos métodos estão descontinuados e mesmo implementando a atualização dos métodos, não estou conseguindo validar a imagem com alguma foto.

Muito obrigado!

Comment: O que você quer dizer com: "validar a imagem com alguma foto"?

Comment: O app deve _" comparar a imagem em vídeo com uma imagem gravada"_ para efetuar reconhecimento facial em tempo real. Eu preciso analisar um rosto em vídeo e compará-lo com outra imagem (blob, .jpg, .png, etc). Terão diversas fotos registradas, o app precisa analisar de quem é o rosto com base neste banco de dados.

Comment: No seu banco de imagens você precisa ter a informação da imagem. Tipo: distancia entre os olhos, distancia dos olhos ao nariz, largura da boca, distancia do nariz a boca, etc. O seu software deve ser capaz de extrair essas mesmas informações da face que esta no vídeo e fazer select no banco desses dados.  De fato, ele nem usa a imagem do banco de dados.

Comment: http://www.faceplusplus.com/demo-detect/

Comment: Certo, existe alguma API que eu possa tratar a imagem da face do banco, tratar em tempo real a imagem do vídeo e compará-las?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/vision/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=2016-q1-cloud-latam-ML-skws-freetrial

Comment: Reginaldo, achei a API bem legal. Mas eu subi uma foto minha e ela trouxe diversos rostos orientais para compara com a minha. (Mesmo não tendo nenhuma linhagem oriental =D ).

Comment: kkkkkkk. Então, precisa afinar esses resultados. Você precisa ter informações suficientes em seu banco para trazer apenas o rosto correto ou a informação de que não há registro no banco de dados.

Comment: Olá. Sua pergunta tá muito ampla porque detecção de face e reconhecimento de face são assuntos relacionados, mas distintos. Além disso, este site não é um fórum, e sim um site de perguntas e respostas objetivas. Portanto, não faça a pergunta como "alguém recomenda isso", mas poste a sua dificuldade específica (vc pode abrir mais de uma pergunta, se tiver mais de uma dificuldade). Sobre reconhecimento de faces, eu sugiro esse artigo do próprio OpenCV: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html

Comment: P.S.: E, sim, eu recomendo fortemente o uso do OpenCV. É a melhor biblioteca pra essa sua intenção, e tem *muito* material na Internet. :)

Comment: Vc vai notar no artigo que geralmente se usa métodos baseados em textura ou diretamente no valor dos pixels da imagem. Nos comentários te sugeriram métodos geométricos (medir distâncias de marcas faciais), mas o problema disso é que detectar essas marcas de forma robusta ainda é um problema em aberto. O OpenCV tem um detector de faces (http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html) bem bom, mas há detectores de marcas faciais razoáveis (sugestão de leitura nesse assunto: http://www.learnopencv.com/facial-landmark-detection/), caso vc queira tentar mesmo assim.